# What really is an unused thread?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I read all the status related to thread. As per my understanding the life cycle of a thread can

New > Runnable/Ready > Waiting/Time_waiting > Blocked [if the thread can not acquire the resource after returning from the wait by notify() or notifyAll() ] > Runnable/Ready > Dead

I do not find a formal definition of "unused thread". I need to know when we can consider a thread as unused thread.

Note: I was reading a conference paper named "
Operating system support for mitigating software scalability bottlenecks on asymmetric multicore processors". You can find it [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1787281).

This paper discussed about a scheduling algorithm. Somewhere in the paper they wrote a line

"In some applications unused threads block during the sequential phase, and by monitoring the application’s runnable thread count, which is exposed to the OS by most threading libraries, the scheduler can trivially detect a sequential phase. In other applications, however, unused threads busy-wait (or spin) during short periods of time, and so the OS cannot detect these phases simply by monitoring the runnable thread count."

Comment: It's not a term I ever use.  Please give some context, a link maybe?

Comment: Ah.. it's a very bad term for 'threads that cannot make forward progress ATM because a resource they require is not currently available'.

Comment: Not sure what is a good terms for such threads.  'Blocked' implies that CPU execution has been withheld by the OS, which excludes those threads that are spinning:(

Comment: Maybe 'stalled'?

Comment: By the meaning of "Unused" it gives a the idea, but I can not understand at which point a thread can be called "unused".